# Twitter intent tweet adding forward slash

Tags: html, url, twitter

I'm following the API guidelines to make a tweet:

`http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Don%27t+hide+your+incessant+curiosity%2E+Exclaim+it%2E+%23quote+http://itechthereforeiam.com+via+@mjbrender`

But it keeps appending a '/' to the end:

> Don't hide your incessant curiosity. Exclaim it. #quote
>   http://itechthereforeiam.com via @mjbrender/

I found a few conversations headed this direction, but nothing answering the question.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if you ever got this to work, but I moved the via statement to the "front" and it got rid of the slash.

For example:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?via=UserName&amp;url=http://MyURL.com&amp;text=Share your Story and Win!&amp;hashtags=myHashTag&amp;
```

I previously had the via tag at the end and it would product the slash. With this code, the via still appears at the end, rather than the beginning of the message, just without the trailing forward slash.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please note that while this might work, there are still some encoding issues with the url as explained by David's answer below... at a minimum the ":" should be encoded.

Some additional encoding info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding

Answer (score 3):

It's because you don't URL-encode MyURL.
Try this :

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Don%27t+hide+your+incessant+curiosity.+Exclaim+it.+%23quote+http%3A//itechthereforeiam.com+via+@mjbrender
```